# mechanism to get element from the list

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

is it possible to get element from the list in SML of New Jersey without using function head and tail, something like that:

```
val a = [1,2,3];
a[1];
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the function `List.nth`, which takes a tuple containing a list and an index and returns the element at that index. So in your example, it'd be `List.nth (a, 1)`.

Note however that accessing the `n`th element of a linked list is `O(n)`, so if you use `List.nth` to iterate through a list, you'll end up with quadratic running time.